# How to avoid refreshing recyclerview refreshing on viewpager swipe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablelayout

In my android application the app structure according to feature requirement is as follows:

MainActivity has a Frame layout and a MainFragment.
When Activity onCreate method is called main fragment is setup on frame layout.
In MainFragment there is a Viewpager and a Tablayout.
Viewpager loads 5 Fragments lets say Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3, Fragment4, Fragment5
Each Fragment has a recyclerview.
All Fragments share same Recyclerview.Adapter the data is set accordingly.

Issue:
When app is loaded and MainFragment is setup all fragments are loaded at once as i have used `viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4` but on swipe the recyclerview's `onBindViewHolder` method is called again and again which causes recyclerview data to blink and it all ends up in lagging on viewpager swipe.

Below is my code part

**MainFragment.kt**

```
@Keep
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfragment, container, false)
        mainActivity = activity as MainActivity
        return rootView
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            BottomNavFragment().apply {

            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setUpTabLayout()
       
    }

    private fun setUpTabLayout() {
        try {
                val adapter = FileViewPagerAdapterTEST(childFragmentManager)
                adapter.addFragments()
                viewPager.adapter = adapter
                viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4
                viewPager.currentItem = 1
                // viewPager.post { viewPager.currentItem = 1 }
                viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
                    override fun onPageScrolled(
                        position: Int,
                        positionOffset: Float,
                        positionOffsetPixels: Int
                    ) {

                    }

                    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                        mainActivity.clearSearch()
                    }

                    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                    }

                })
               tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.icimg)
tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.icimgg)
tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.icimggg)
tabLayout.getTabAt(3)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.icimggggg)
tabLayout.getTabAt(4)?.icon = mainActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.icimgggggg)

tabLayout.getTabAt(0)?.text = getString(R.string.text1)
tabLayout.getTabAt(1)?.text = getString(R.string.text2)
tabLayout.getTabAt(2)?.text = getString(R.string.text3)
tabLayout.getTabAt(3)?.text = getString(R.string.text4)
tabLayout.getTabAt(4)?.text = getString(R.string.text5)
         
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


}
```

**mainfragment.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round_view_white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/ThemeTextAppearanceTab">

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ViewPager Adapter**

```
class FileViewPagerAdapterTEST(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(
    fm,
    BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT
) {
    val fragments = arrayListOf<Fragment>()

    fun addFragments() {
       fragments.add(Fragment1())
        fragments.add(Fragment2())
       fragments.add(Fragment3())
        fragments.add(Fragment4())
        fragments.add(Fragment5())
    }

    override fun getItem(pos: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[pos]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

**Fragment1.kt** (Funtionality in all child fragments is implemented same way)

```
    @Keep
    class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

    private val fragmentViewModel: FileFragmentsViewModel by viewModel()
    private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private val sharedPreferencesManager = get<SharedPreferencesManager>()
    private val repository = get<FilesRepository>()
    private var listAdapter: ListRowItemAdapter? = null
    private var tabType = TabType.ALL

    private var listOfTab2 = mutableListOf<MyModelClass>()
    private var listOfTab3 = mutableListOf<MyModelClass>()
    private var lisOfTab1 = mutableListOf<MyModelClass>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        try {
            fragmentViewModel.loadAllFiles()
            listAdapter = ListRowItemAdapter(
                sharedPreferencesManager,
                fragmentViewModel,
                activityViewModel,
                repository,
                inflater.context,
            )
            refreshFilesOnAdapter()
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }

        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            layoutProgress.visibility = View.GONE
            val ll = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            ll.isSmoothScrollbarEnabled = false;
            setUpRecyclerView(ll, null)
            handleViewModelObservers()
        }, 2000)

    }


    private fun setUpRecyclerView(
        layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
        filesToSet: MutableList<MyModelClass>?
    ) {
        //   rvAllFiles.itemAnimator=null
        // (rvAllFiles.itemAnimator as DefaultItemAnimator).supportsChangeAnimations = false
        // rvAllFiles.itemAnimator?.changeDuration=0
        (rvAllFiles.itemAnimator as SimpleItemAnimator).supportsChangeAnimations = false
        rvAllFiles.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        rvAllFiles.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rvAllFiles.adapter = listAdapter
        if (filesToSet != null) {
            when (tabType) {
                TabType.TYPE1 -> {
                    listAdapter!!.setDataList(fragmentName, filesToSet, TabType.TYPE1)
                }
                TabType.TYPE2 -> {
                    listAdapter!!.setDataList(fragmentName, filesToSet, TabType.TYPE2)
                }
                TabType.TYPE3 -> {
                    listAdapter!!.setDataList(fragmentName, filesToSet, TabType.TYPE3)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleViewModelObservers() {
        observeBottomTabChange()
    }

    private fun observeBottomTabChange() {
        //Bottom navigation menu change (i.e Documents,Recent,Bookmarks)
        activityViewModel.selectedFragmentMain.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            { changedTabType ->
                listAdapter!!.setCurrentBottomTabType(fragmentName, changedTabType)
                tabType = changedTabType
            })
    }
    private fun refreshFilesOnAdapter() {
        fragmentViewModel.getAllItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
            { filesList ->
                lisOfAllItems = filesList
                listAdapter!!.setAllItemsList(filesList)

            })
        fragmentViewModel.getLiveDataFromDb()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { filesList ->
            fragmentViewModel.getAllItems().postValue(
                fragmentViewModel.checkFilesWithDB(
                    filesList,
                    fragmentViewModel.getAllItems().value
                )
            )
            fragmentViewModel.getTab2FileFromDB(FileType.ALL)
                ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
                    { tab2list ->
                        listOfTab2 = tab2list
                        listAdapter!!.setttab2list(
                            listOfTab2
                                .toMutableList().asReversed()
                        )
                    })
            fragmentViewModel.getTab3FileFromDB
            (FileType.ALL)
                ?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
                    { tab3list ->
                        listOfTab3 = tablist3

                        listAdapter!!.setttab3list
                        (listOfTab3
                    })
        })
    }
}
```

**fragment_first.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/rvAllFiles" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_fragment_list_status"
        android:id="@+id/layoutNoResults"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/layout_fragment_list_progress"
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How this lag issue can be solved so that when MainActivity is loaded and MainFragment is set on it all fragments are loaded at once and Viewpager retains them so that on swipe only loaded fragment data should be displayed instead of refreshing Recyclerviews of fragments.
Can somebody please help me out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show fragment with recycler view implementation

Comment: @StanislavBondar Updated